# c# - Why can't my Dictionary class see the ToArray() method?

Tags: c#, dictionary, extension-methods

I see in the API Dictionary has a ToArray() method (in the extension classes area), but when I try to use this from my Dictionary instance it can't see it???

How do I "enable" ToArray() for my Dictionary instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `Dictonary<TKey,TValue>` class does not actually have a `.ToArray` method.  There is an extension method called `.ToArray` which can bind to `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.  But this requires that System.Linq be one of your usings.

Have you verified that System.Linq is imported?

Example:

```
using System.Linq;
...
public void Example() {
  var map = new Dictionary<string,string>();
  ..
  var arr = map.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: thanks - how come VS2008 wouldn't offer me a way to "resolve" this and add the "using" line for me?

Comment: @Greg, resolving imports for extension methods is a bit more work than resolving types.  It's usually on the list but cost usually causes it to not make it.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably targeting .NET 2.0, which doesn't support Extension methods. Try changing your application to target .Net 3.5